# Why is webelement not showing up in selenium? Regardless of find method

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, safari, qwebelement

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to locate the "Confirm Booking" button in selenium. My driver is on the current webpage and we can see in the html that the button is of class "menubutton". Yet when I iterate through all elements of that class it only locates the "Return to timetable" button. As you can see in the terminal output.

My code is as follows:

```
#confirms booking
elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'menubutton')
print(len(elems))
for e in elems:
    print(e.text)
```

I have also tried locating by XPATH but it only finds the "Return to Class Timetable" button.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What error are you receiving here? what is the output of `print(len(elems))`? can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet So their are two buttons of class "menubutton", the "Return to class timetable" button and "confirm booking" button. The output of print(len(elems)) is 1 and the output of print(e.text) is "Return to class timetable" so it is only finding that 1 button. It also returns the "Return to class time table" button when I search for it by XPATH. I can't get the exact link since it requires a login ID but if you submit() on this link it will take you there:

Comment: The link is too long to comment but you follow this site: https://hub.ucd.ie/usis/W_HU_MENU.P_PUBLISH?p_tag=GYMBOOK

Comment: To get in I need Membership Number. Also, in case `print(len(elems))` gives you 1 there is no 2 elements matching `menubutton` class name there, only 1.

Comment: @Prophet Right I guess there is only 1. Any suggestions on how to find the "Confirm Booking" web element then? Already tried by By.XPATH.

Comment: To help with that I need to get access to that web page or you will have to give me the XML / HTML of that page. Not a picture and not of that element only but of all the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242158/discussion-between-pythonfanatic999-and-prophet).